# Nsis script fails to create two installers?

Tags: nsis

I have to create two conditional exes using the same nsis script. But it fails with error:

> deflatetofile fwrite failed. Aborting creation process.

Can I get immediate help on this?

Comment: can you post script what you have tried??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the internal process of file compression fails.

Do you have enough space on disk? Have you checked the rights (write access) where you are trying to create the installer?